# My problem is to upload the font to web site

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

The main problem was that the font was displayed differently than it should, although everything was connected correctly.
I managed to find the source in html and css where it is shown how to use this font and it began to appear as it should.
The only suggestion as to why the font did not work is that this font in ttf format does not work on the web.

Thank u everyone for the help!

```css
/* #### Generated By: http://www.cufonfonts.com #### */

@font-face {
font-family: 'Voya Nui';
font-style: normal;
font-weight: normal;
src: local('Voya Nui'), url('VoyaNui_1.15_4.woff') format('woff');
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8"/>
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"
          href="style.css"/>
</head>

<body>

<h1 style="font-family:'Voya Nui';font-weight:normal;font-size:65px">018.0204  BIOLOGICAL CHRONICLE</h1>


</body>
</html>
```

Comment: You cannot link fonts to a webpage by using the `<link rel="stylesheet">` element and supplying a ttf file. The font must be imported using a regular stylesheet with an `@font-face` definition, and then using it in a style definition.

Answer (score 1):

You can't do `<link rel="stylesheet" href="fonts/VoyaNui_1.15_4.ttf">`.

You need to use **@font-face** in css or style.

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'VoyaNui';
  src:   url('./fonts/VoyaNui_1.15_4') format('woff2'),
    url('./fonts/VoyaNui_1.15_4') format('woff'),
    url('./fonts/VoyaNui_1.15_4') format('ttf');
}
```

One more thing, I use woff and woff2, because it has a good compression, but be careful with some browsers (IE).

See in caniuse https://caniuse.com/#search=woff and https://caniuse.com/#search=woff2

Comment: Thank u for your answers!

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your pasted stylesheet is `styles.css`, add the font-face definition before your `body` rule:

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'VoyaNui',
    src: url('fonts/VoyaNui_1.15_4.ttf');
}
body {
    font-family: 'VoyaNui';
}
```

Then remove the `<link>` to the font, it will not work.

Comment: Thank you for your answers, but unfortunately it did not help with this font.

I corrected everything you advised in style.css and deleted the link in index.html

Perhaps the font is some kind of custom and the usual way is not suitable here.

After editing, I cleaned the files in the cache, it also did not produce results.

Comment: Check the network tab of your browser, if it is at least trying to load the font. If not, something is wrong with your font-face definition.

Comment: The following thing is shown in the console "Resource interpreted as Stylesheet but transferred with MIME type application/octet-stream: "file:///Users/aleksey/Downloads/Abu/fonts/VoyaNui_1.15_4.ttf"."

Comment: Now, that's just plain nonsense. It should not want to interpret it as a stylesheet. Could you please post an update with your current code?

Comment: Everything looks ok to me. Dumb question: Is your .ttf file REALLY a ttf file, or is it, as the error message suggests, actually a stylesheet that contains the style definitions? I.e. can you open the .ttf file in Notepad and check, whether it is actually binary or if it is text?

Comment: Thanks for your reply. 
Font is changing, but not quite properly. Look at this link cufonfonts.com/font/voya-nui-gf the font looks a little cropped around the edges, but on my site it looks completely different. Maybe you have an idea why this is happening?)

Comment: Sorry, without being able to see anything, I won't be able to help. But, this might be a good starting point for another question, since this original question seems to have been answered. Marking the answer is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to generate the fonts from online web font generator and after the generation of fonts put the woff and woff2 generated fonts in your fonts folder.

```
@font-face {
    font-family: 'VoyaNui';
    src: url(./fonts/VoyaNui_1.15_4) format('ttf'), url(./fonts/VoyaNui_1.15_4) format('woff'), url(./fonts/VoyaNui_1.15_4) format('woff2');
}
```

Comment: Thank u, I managed to find the source in html and css where it is shown how to use this font and it began to appear as it should.